# Toggle button visibility based on individual/global search inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, filtering

I have a table with the "Clear All" button to allow the user to instantly remove all individual-column filters and global searches at the same time. [This is a table that contains both types of filters](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html).

The following [code](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33405/clear-the-datatable-column-filters-using-a-button) accomplishes the resetting when the button is clicked:

```
<button type="button" id="test" class="btn btn-primary">Clear Filters</button>

<script>
$('#test').click(function() {
     $("#MyTable").DataTable().search("").draw(); // clears global search bar
     $('#MyTable tfoot input').val('').change();  // clears individual column filters
     $(this).hide();
});
</script>
```

But, I want the button to be **hidden** when there is no text in the individual column search bars in `<tfoot>` nor in the global search bar. I want the button to reappear as soon as the user enters any text.

This code ([src](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33405/clear-the-datatable-column-filters-using-a-button), [src](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnFilterClear)) works to monitor the global search input, but does not keep track of the individual column search bars:

```
$('#MyTable').on('search.dt', function() {
    var value = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
    alert(value); // <-- the value
});
```

So, is there a way to check if both types of search bars are empty, so that I can hide and show the "Clear All" button as described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may listen for `keyup` within all `<input>` elements inside DataTables wrapper and [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) your button if any those contains any characters and [`show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) it otherwise:

```
$('.dataTables_wrapper input').on('keyup', () => {
    if([...$('.dataTables_wrapper input')].some(input => $(input).val().length > 0) $('#test').hide();
    else $('#test').show();
});
```

Following **demo** illustrates that approach:

```js
//sample source data
const srcData = [
  {item: 'apple', type: 'fruit', qty: 5},
  {item: 'pear', type: 'fruit', qty: 4},
  {item: 'banana', type: 'fruit', qty: 7},
  {item: 'carrot', type: 'vegie', qty: 14},
  {item: 'goosberry', type: 'berry', qty: 6}
];

//initialize DataTables
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  dom: 'ft',
  data: srcData,
  columns: ['item', 'type', 'qty'].map(header => ({title: header, data: header})),
});

//append footer
$('#mytable').append('<tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>');
//populate that with input fields
dataTable.columns().every(function(){
  $('#mytable tfoot tr').append(`<td><input colindex="${this.index()}" placeholder="${$(this.header()).text()}"></input></td>`);
});

//filter upon column inputs
$('#mytable').on('keyup', 'tfoot input', function(){
  dataTable.column($(this).attr('colindex')).search($(this).val()).draw();
});

//implement clearall button
$('#clearall').on('click', () => {
  //empty all inputs
  [...$('.dataTables_wrapper input')].forEach(input => $(input).val(''));
  //clear individual columns search
  dataTable.columns().every(function(){this.search('')});
  //clear global search
  dataTable.search('');
  //re-draw
  dataTable.draw();
});

//toggle 'clearall' button visibility
$('.dataTables_wrapper input').on('keyup', () => {
    if([...$('.dataTables_wrapper input')].some(input => $(input).val().length > 0)) $('#clearall').show();
    else $('#clearall').hide();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="mytable"></table>
<button id="clearall" hidden>Clear all</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Note, that 'clearall' button is hidden by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
$('#myInputTextField1, #myInputTextField2').val('');
table.search('').draw(); //required after
});
```

check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4rvmtv7d/
Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid that you've misunderstood my question. I am not asking how to clear the filters on button click; the code in the OP already accomplishes this. I am asking how to hide the button if the input fields contain zero text.